# jQuery on() instead of live() doesn't work

Tags: jquery

Since .live() has been deprecated, i'm using .on() instead of .live(), but it doesn't work properly, bear me if i am wrong, thanks in advance.

Below is a simple testing html, my expect behavior is that event fire only when i click the button, but it turns out event fires wherever i click.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>demo</title>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <button id="btn">Click</button>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
    <p>Hello World!</p>
</div>
<script>

$(document).on("click", $("#btn"), function(){ 

    document.title += "fire!";

});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The second parameter to `on()` function should be the `selector` not the `jQuery object`.

```
$(document).on("click", "#btn", function(){ 
    document.title += "fire!";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/LWCKh/3/)

Use this as your script

```
$(function(){
   $('#btn').on('click', function(){
      alert('You clicked a button.');
   });
});
```